# Encrypt my Ubuntu fileshare

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, samba

I want to setup a simple Ubuntu fileserver and have the Samba share encrypted. The trick is that I want to be able to simply power the server on and have the Samba shared files accessible to the network with permissions.

I know I can simply tell Ubuntu to encrypt my home folder and then create a share in a folder under my home folder. That would encrypt the files, but decryption only happens when I login. If the power goes out and the server reboots upon power coming back on, nobody would be able to access the fileshares until I logged in.

There has to be a better, more secure way.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible on the system itself. If the key to decrypt the data is stored locally, it must be stored unencrypted. Therefore, the system is effectively not encrypted.

My best suggestion is to have the key stored somewhere in the network in a place you consider secure, then have the box retrieve it and decrypt the files on boot. Still a bad idea, but slightly more secure.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you actually mean "encrypt your fileshare".  If this is the case, you probably can't do it (short of encrypting the files on top of the share) and/or the backing device - neither of which are SAMBA related.  What you can, however do, is password protect the shares so users need a password (or access to the server) to access files.  (See [this link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9159/how-do-i-ensure-data-encryption-on-samba-transmission-on-nix-systems) on security.stackexchange)

[This link](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html) talks about password protecting stuff.  Basically you need to set u a list of users and passwords SAMBA can handle, and then set "valid users" for that resource.   For example appropriate code snippets might be-

```
[global]
    security = user
    encrypt passwords = yes
    smb passwd file = /usr/local/samba/private/smbpasswd

[sales]
            path = /home/sales
            comment = Sedona Real Estate Sales Data
            writable = yes
            valid users = sofie shelby adilia
            admin users = mike
```

You can use smbpasswd to maintain the database of passwords.

Comment: My concern is that if someone were to break in and steal the server, they'd have access to the hard drive and all the files. I know I can secure it via samba but that doesn't do much if someone physically takes the server.